# React Modal I want to be able to scroll a modal when it is vertically long

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

I am using react-modal.
I would like to be able to scroll the modal vertically when the screen is small.
Currently, when the screen is small, the modal cannot be scrolled, so you cannot see the whole modal.

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-elgamal-2dl00?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1149)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Modal from "react-modal";

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setModal] = useState(true);

  const Container = styled.div<{ height?: string }>`
    width: 400px;
    height: ${({ height }) => (height ? height : "")};
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #ffffff;
  `;

  const customStyles = {
    overlay: {
      background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
    },
    content: {
      top: "50%",
      left: "50%",
      right: "auto",
      bottom: "auto",
      marginRight: "-50%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
      padding: "0"
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModal(false);
        }}
        contentLabel="modal"
        style={customStyles}
      >
        <p>Modal</p>
        <Container height={"600px"}></Container>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 const customStyles = {
    overlay: {
      background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
    },
    content: {
      ...//
      height:"200px" //or maxHeight 
    }
  };
```

add a fixed height or maxHeight to the modal

To scroll your entire modal you can use this style

```
 const customStyles = {
    overlay: {
      background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
      overflowY:"scroll"
    },
    content: {
     // your code
    }
  };
```

Comment: I have added height, but the Modal does not scroll.
I don't want to scroll inside the Modal, I want to scroll the Modal itself.

Comment: The best method is scroll contents inside your modal, if you want to scroll entire modal you cal add overflow-y: "scroll" style will add it in my answer

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-elgamal-2dl00?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I added overflowY, but could not scroll.

Comment: You have added it to container, please add id to custom_styles, overlay, check my updated answer

Comment: const customStyles = {
    overlay: {
      background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
      overflowY:"scroll"
    }, ......

Comment: Sorry, I tried to create it in codesandbox.
I can scroll, but the top part of the modal is cut off.

Comment: This is why I said set modal with equal to the window.innerHeight and set scroll to the content in modal

Comment: remove overflowY from overlay, and "height: window.innerHeight" add this to your content

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-elgamal-2dl00?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-swanson-9r7oh?file=/src/App.tsx check this

Comment: ↑I can't scroll.

Comment: it is scrolling, working fine in above example, you are trying some wrong way I think

Comment: The contents are scrolling.
I want to scroll the modal.

Comment: overflowY:"scroll" - to the outer div of the modal - mouse rotator scrolls modal first - straight solution - good to me